# I removed all permissions on C:\ Server 2012 R2 Core

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-core

Really stupid move, I know this. I was granting permissions to one of our users on the C: directory of on of our servercore machines. I used `icacls /grant :r` and removed all the permissions to the drive, except the one I was granting. I an still log in, but have no way to fix this. Does anybody have any help for me?

Comment: If you are logged in with administrator you should still be able to take ownership, and then you can reset permissions.  See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-restore-default-security-permissions/ab58f918-da72-42c0-ba71-161d52b73d46.  Just Google for "Windows reset default permissions on c drive" and find something that works.

Comment: I was able to figure things out, and get permissions back. The first thing I did was open a powershell session from a machine with a GUI, and used the takeown command to get ownership of C: I then used a powershell program I found to create an new ACL for C:, which gave me full control. I was then able to edit permissions as needed to restore them using icacls. I also had to change ownership back to NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller. All is well now, but it didnt make for a very fun weekend.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.  Be careful out there!